# invalid type argument of the unary '*' (have int)

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, dereference

As you can see I have used the `printf` function to print a 2D array using pointers, but I am getting the error of invalid type argument. To check I tried printing the below code where I take `k` and pointer `c` to print the value of `k`. I have no errors

```
int main ()
{

    int a[3][2]={2,5,9,11,23,46};
    int *p;
    p=&a[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=1;j++)
        {
            printf("\n value of the 2 d array: %d",*(*(p+i)+j));
        }
    }
    int k=6;
    int *c;
    c=&k;
    printf("%d",*c);
}
```

Comment: `*(p+i*2+j)`? (I'm not sure if this invokes undefined behavior)

Comment: @Subhendu Nayak What is unclear with the error message?

Comment: `*(p+i)` is an integer and `*(p+i) +j` is an integer and there is no `*(integer)` defined. As MikeCAT said use `*(p + 2*i + j)` .

Comment: i have checked all my syntaxes and when I tried running the code it specifically mentions the line containing *(*(p+i)+j)); and states invalid type argument of the unary '*' (have int).

Comment: Instead of using hard-coded numbers to define the array size, loop conditions and possibly index calculations you should define constants and them in all corresponding places. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the full error message and format it as a code block. [susanth29](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16553790/susanth29)'s comment explains why your pointer dereferencing is wrong.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Given `p = &a[0][0];`, `p` points to an element in an `int [2]`, and `p+i*2+j` is defined only for 0 ≤ `i*2+j` ≤ 2, per C 2018 6.5.6. Even though there are more `int` objects in memory after `a[0][1]`, the pointer arithmetic is not defined outside of the elements in `a[0]` and its notional endpoint, `&a[0][2]`. Further, since the `+i*2` is performed first, `p+i*2+j` is defined only when both 0 ≤ `i*2` ≤ 2 and 0 ≤ `i*2+j` ≤ 2 are satisfied.

Comment: @susanth29: `*(p + 2*i + j)` is wrong, per my prior comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you saying it doesn't work or it's not suggested to do so, as it may cause undefined befavior.

Comment: @susanth29:  Because the behavior is not defined by the C standard, we cannot know the code will work (unless perhaps a compiler specifies it will work as an extension to the language). There are situations in which compiler optimization may break code that attempts to access subarrays out of bounds.

Comment: "print a 2D array using pointers," why, Why, WHY are you doing such things. It makes no sense at all

Answer (score 3):

You declared a pointer to `int`

```
int *p;
```

So you may dereference it only once and if you will do that you will get an object of the type `int` to which you may not apply the unary operator *.

That is in this expression

```
*(*(p+i)+j)
```

the sub-expression

```
*(p+i)
```

already has the type `int`. And as a result this sube-expression `*(p+i)+j` also has the type `int` that you are trying to dereference.

You need to declare the pointer `p` the following way

```
int ( *p )[2];
p = a;
```

Now the expression

```
(p+i)
```

points to the `i-th` "row" of the two-dimensional array `a`. Dereferencing the pointer expression

```
*(p+i)
```

you will get that "row" that is an array of the type `int[2]`. Used in expressions it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. Thus this expression

```
*(p+i)+j
```

has the type `int *` and points to the `j-th` element of the `i-th` "row" of the array `a`.

Dereferencing this pointer expression

```
*(*(p+i)+j)
```

you will get the `j-th` element of the `i-th` "row".

Answer (score 1):

Since `p` has type `int *`, the expression `*(p + i)` has type `int`, therefore `*(p + i) + j` has type `int` and cannot be dereferenced.

Replace the expression `*(*(p + i) + j)` with `*p++`:

```
printf("\n value of the 2 d array: %d", *p++);
```

The will "walk" `p` through the array; it starts pointing to `a[0][0]`, and the `++` operator advances the pointer to point to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because `*(*(p+i)+j)` is invalid lets break it down:

`(*p+i)` `p` stores the address of the first element in the 2d array which is 2. You have added the value of i to the address, then you encase it in `*()` which deference's the address and returns a integer.

The expression now will look like this in the first iteration:

`*(*(p+0)+j)`

`*(2+j)` // this becomes invalid since you are deferencing a integer

The way you can fix this is simple. Make a pointer to an array of integers.

`int (*p)[2] = a;`

The reason for this is because it is easier to move through a 2d array with this since your array has 3 rows of 2 columns:

`int a[3][2]={2,5,9,11,23,46};`

which you can image looks like this visually:

```
{2,5}

{9,11}

{23,46}
```

Now as you may be able to see if we refer to each array individually it becomes easier.

```
int main ()
{
    int a[3][2]={2,5,9,11,23,46};

    int (*p)[2] = a;

    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=1;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(*(p+i)+j));
        }
    }
}
```

lets break down `*(*(p+i)+j)` this time:

`*(p+i)` p stores the address of the first array then we add i to it and deference it taking us to the first element of the array. We then add j aka move along the array. lastly the outer most `*()` de-references this address and gives us a int value to print.